# Function not firing .click() programmatically

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I can't seem to figure out why the following Javascript function won't fire:

```
function onUploadDone(success, recordName, duration, recorderId) {

    document.getElementById("dwl").disabled = false
    document.getElementById("firstDisplay").innerHTML = "Last JS callback: onUploadDone()"
    document.getElementById("<%= btnFbAuth.ClientID%>").click();
}
```

The button is wrapped in a div whose style is set to "display: none:", but other than that, I can't figure out why its not firing. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: It was due to not having semi colons terminating the first two getElement snippets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to go to server side by triggering this button' onclick event then, you can do it easily by using;

```
__dopostback("<%= btnFbAuth.ClientID%>",'').
```